# okHttp NetworkOnMainThreadException despite to new Thread

Tags: java, android, exception, networking, okhttp

In android studio project I am using okhttp to send post requests.

```
public void sentRequest(.... ....) {

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("number", number).build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(serverBase + API_numberAvailabilityCheck).post(formBody).build();
        call = client.newCall(request);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final HashMap<String, Object> requestResult = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    final Response response = call.execute();
                } 
                ...........
                ...........
            }
        }).run();

}
```

But it throws an `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception on line where I am calling `final Response response = call.execute();` despite to `new Thread`. Why it's throwing like exception? And how to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: OkHttp can handle threading for you. Use `enqueue()` instead of `execute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is

`thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()`.

Calling the `run()` method the code is running in the same thread, without starting new thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a huge mistake here ..

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }).run();
```

You should call `start()` on thread to start not `run()` .. If you call run() directly then There will be No thread running and Your `Thread` will just act like a normal java class with a normal method `run()`..

You should be using

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}).start();
```

On a side note a better approach to networking in android you should be using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) .. Its way too easy to use and it also uses `OkHttp` under the hood.. And you do not have to worry about creating thread anymore..